# Unable to extract features using huggingface swin transformer model

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, swin-transformer

I need to use swin transfomer as a backbone for my SVM model. I need to extract the features first, therefore I am trying to remove the last layer and train the model. This is a sample executable code.

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
import torchvision
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
import numpy as np

HUB_URL = "SharanSMenon/swin-transformer-hub:main"
MODEL_NAME = "swin_tiny_patch4_window7_224"
model = torch.hub.load(HUB_URL, MODEL_NAME, pretrained=True)
model = nn.Sequential(*list(model.children())[:-1])          #--> If you comment this line, the code is executing
for param in model.parameters():
    param.requires_grad = False


dummy_tensor = torch.randn(32, 3, 224, width)

# Print the shape of the dummy tensor
model(dummy_tensor)
```

[image]

What am I missing, I tried the same process with resnet50 and it worked fine. Why am I not able to remove the last layer and get only the output features? what should I do? any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The two models have different `forward` logic. If you inspect the result of `nn.Sequential(*list(model.children())[:-1])`, you'll see you're putting a `ModuleList` into a `Sequential` block which doesn't make sense. The specific error is trying to call the `forward` method of `ModuleList` which isn't implemented.

You need to adapt your logic to each model architecture.